# Geometry find the angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, congruences-geometry

Good day, excuse me, I am looking at congruence themes in Geometry, and I am trying to solve this problem, but I am not sure how to proceed. The coloured numbers is what I have so far (although now looking at it, my angles could be wrong). Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I am curious about the origin of this problem because I have never seen people using the notation $\hat{X}$ to represent an angle. Is this notation commonly used in your region?

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang Wow, I didn't know, Yourong. I am from Mexico, I am just starting in Maths, so I wasn't aware that there's different ways of writing angles in different countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join $AB$. Then $AM=MB \Rightarrow \triangle AMB$ is equilateral.

Hence in $\triangle BAD$, $\angle BAD=60+30=90$ and $AD=AB$. Thus $\angle ADB = \angle ABD=45$.

Therefore the exterior $\angle X=\angle ADB + \angle DAM=75 $

Comment: Wow, thank you, cosmo5. It's so enlightening, and such an eye opener. Thank you, and for all the suggestions of ways of solving it :)